# Azure Pipelines does not recognize mvn in self hosted agent

Tags: java, bash, maven, azure-devops, jmeter

I have already installed maven on my own agent and when I run the command `mvn -v` from putty I get this output:

> Maven home: /opt/maven Java version: 1.8.0_292, vendor: Private Build,
> runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre Default locale: en_US,
> platform encoding: UTF-8 OS name: "linux", version:
> "4.15.0-1071-azure", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"

With this output **I make sure maven is installed correctly** and has environment variables set correctly.

But when I run maven tasks on this agent from azure devops I get the **following error message**:

> ##[error]Unhandled: Unable to locate executable file: 'mvn'. Please verify either the file path exists or the file can be found within a
> directory specified by the PATH environment variable. Also check the
> file mode to verify the file is executable.

I tried running only an azure devops bash task that would execute the command `mvn -v` and **I get the following error**:

> mvn: command not found

I would appreciate your support as I am sure Maven is well installed and configured but for some reason azure devops does not recognize these commands

Comment: Have you restarted the azure devops agent since you installed Maven?

Comment: yes, I already restarted it and it still does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried many ways but none worked.

finally it occurred to me to assign the environment variables from azure devops.

First, I tried creating a bash task that would run the command `export M2_HOME=/opt/maven` but it didn't work.

Then i tried azure own instructions: `echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=M2_HOME]/opt/maven"` and it worked fine.

The concrete solution was to create two tasks before the maven tasks that assigned all the necessary environment variables, as follows:

[image]

tasks run the following commands:

[image]

[image]

**NOTE:** A*ssignment does not work in a single task because the second task uses a variable that is assigned in the first.
if it is to define a variable and use it in the same task it will not work.*

Comment: Is there any option for windows?

Comment: works perfectly thanks!